# How to handle the exceptions using Spring AOP before reaching the endpoint

Tags: json, spring-boot, spring-aop

I have a spring controller where the endpoint is defined

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/hello", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public Map<String, String> hello() {
    .....
}
```

In my aspect class, I have,

```
@Around("execution(* org.example.metrics.dropwizard.SampleController.hello(..))")
public Object aroundCallingHello(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable
{ 
}
```

Lets say, My endpoint takes a java object as a parameter (POST call) to save in the database.
Request from the webpage is in JSON. If the JSON structure is not matching the JAVA POJO structure, there is an exception thrown. But i am not able to catch that exception in the Aspect class (aroundCallingHello method doesn't work). How to catch such kind of exceptions (where the request not even reached the endpoint in controller) in AOP. I need to track all kinds of exceptions in the application. Thank you.

Comment: Can you show the code in `aroundCallHello` method.

Comment: `   try{   System.out.println("Chiru at aroundCallingHello !!! ");               counterService.increment("method.invoke.hello");
         return joinPoint.proceed();  }

Comment: please see this : `   try{   System.out.println("at aroundCallingHello !!! ");               counterService.increment("method.invoke.hello");
         return joinPoint.proceed();  }                                         catch(Throwable tr) {   System.out.println("at catch aroundCallingHello !!! ");   } `     none of the statements are printing in the console

Comment: I am getting a JsonGenerationException for some of the requests and i need to log those in counters in the Aspect class. Any advice is appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `@ControllerAdvice` in order to achieve these kinds of exception handling. You can find a full [explanation with example here](https://spring.io/blog/2013/11/01/exception-handling-in-spring-mvc). You can have a method (or multiple methods) to handle different types of Exceptions (including if you have any Custom Exceptions). Hope this helps!